# Maintain the displayed content of a file when imported another file in Svelte

Tags: file, svelte

I'm studying svelte and I'm doing some experiments, but i can't figure out how I can do this: when i import a file, and i display it, i save it in a `<pre>` tag, but, if i want to update later another file, obviously, it overwrite everything. There is the code:

```
<script>
let files;
</script>


<input type='file' multiple bind:files accept=".txt">

{#if files}
    <h2>Files selected: </h2>
{#each Array.from(files) as file}
    <p>The imported file is: {file.name}</p>
{#await file.text() then text}
    <pre>{text}</pre>
{/await}
{/each}
{/if}
```

And this is the examples files:
File 1

> I'm an example file!

File2

> I'm another example file!

File3:

> And i was imported after

So i import toghether File1 and File2, but if I import after them the File3, it gives me this:

```
And i was imported afer
```

How can i add the newest file to the others?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are using `bind:files`, `files` will always reflect the files that were selected last. If you want to keep a list of files that is independent of the file input then you can't bind to it. Listen to the `change` or `input` event and add the files to the list yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

**1) without using bind**

The first method is stop using `bind:files` and manage the files array yourself when the user adds files.

```html
<script>
  let files = [];
  function handleChange(ev) {       
    files = [...ev.target.files, ...files]
  }
</script>

<input type='file' multiple on:change={handleChange} accept=".txt">

<!-- markup goes here -->
{#each files as file}
 ...
{/each}
```

**2) using bind and a second array**

With this method you can still use the `bind:files` syntax, but you do not actually use the *files* variable, but instead copy the content of this array in a second array which you then use:

```html
<script>
  let files = []
  let _files = []
  $: _files = [...files, ..._files]
</script>

<!-- markup goes here, but use _files instead -->
{#each _files as file}
 ...
{/each}
```

As a bonus both cases do not require the `Array.from` anymore because the spread syntax does that! However now you will have to check the length of the array instead in your if because now `files` (or `_files`) always exists.

You might however be interested in knowing that you can do:

```html
{#each array as item}
  something with item
{:else}
  array is empty
{/each}
```

so you do not need the `#if` anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have understood some new concepts.... I would have never got there by myself, also because I'm not a ninja neither in svelte nor in js. Onestly I prefer the first option, because is less expensive, but I will use in another prj the second one.

Comment: The first option is probably the best because it involves less 'magic' and is easier to understand if somebody else has to read your code.

Comment: First option is also easier to add some filtering to remove duplicates for what it's worth

Comment: Sorry for the question but any suggestion about filtering the duplicates? I tried to do it by myself, and yeah, i don't know where to start...

Comment: filter them out of `ev.target.files` before adding them to `files`, something along the lines of `ev.target.files.filter(f => !files.includes(f)` but you might have to play around with syntax